# C# 文字列のコンバーター機能の一般的な実装方法について

Tags: c#

タイトルの件、ある文字列を入力として、
決まったルールに則り変換後の値を返却するメソッドを
C#で作成したいと思います。
ただ、いろいろなやり方があると思います。
下記は、私が考えた一例ですが、
一般的なやり方でスマートな方法はありますでしょうか？
OSS等での実装方法等知見がありましたら、ご教示頂きたくよろしくお願いいたします。
(1)if文の羅列　※この方法はあまりきれいではないので採用したくありません。
    string origial = "ORIGINAL";
    string new = string.Empty;
    if(original == "ORIGINAL"){
        new = "ORG";
    }
    else if(original == "ORIGINAL1"){
        new = "ORG1";
    }

(2)Dictionaryに変換マスタを持たせて変換する。
(3)列挙型を定義して変換する。

なお、メモリ容量を気にするほど大量に定義があるわけではありません。（数百のオーダー）
また、パフォーマンスもそこまでシビアに求めておりません。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

どのようなルールを想定しているのでしょうか？

ad hocなルールなら変換ルールをDictionaryに持たせるのが素直な対処方法だと思います。
IF構文や列挙型を使う方法は、ルールが変更された際のコード修正が面倒ですし、コードから変換ルールを読み取るのも煩わしいので、お勧めできません。

正規表現に書き換えられるルールなら、正規表現を使うのが良いと思います。

Comment: ad hocなルールです。
（"AA" → "TEST"、"BB" → "LABEL"などキーに対してどのような値になるかは、
  定義したルールとなり、正規表現等で決まった法則で変換できるわけではない。）

Enumの場合はカスタムラベルで変換前と変換後の値を定義するつもりです。
この場合、コードの修正工数はDictionaryもEnumも変わらないと思います。

Dictionaryで持つ場合は、メモリ使用量等も気になりますが、
パフォーマンスの面ではEnumの場合とそれほどかわらないでしょうか。。

Comment: @mame さん、メモリ使用量を気にするほど大量に定義があるのでしょうか？ パフォーマンスは非常にシビアなのか現実的な速度で構わないのか、等も気になりますが、これらについて質問文に明記していただけますか？

Answer (score 1):

自分でしたら下記のようなレポジトリパターンで管理するでしょうか。

```
public class ResourceRepository {
    private readonly IReadOnlyDictionary<string, string> _map = new Dictionary<string, string> {
        ["ORIGINAL"] = "ORG",
        ["ORIGINAL1"] = "ORG1",
        // ...
    };

    public string Find(string key) {
        string result;
        return _map.TryGetValue(key, out result) ? result : null;
    }

    public bool Contains(string key) {
        return _map.ContainsKey(key);
    }
}
```

使い方はこんな感じ。

```
class Program {
    private static ResourceRepository _resourceRepository = new ResourceRepository();

    private static void Main(string[] args) {
        var key = Console.ReadLine();

        var result = _resourceRepository.Find(key);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

上記はマッピングルールが静的に決まっているシンプルな例ですが、`Add` や `Save` メソッドを用意してプログラマブルにルールを増やしたり、コンストラクタでデータソース（JSON や XML、データベース接続等）を渡してマッピングルールを構築したり、といった拡張が考えられると思います。